# Редирект со старых динамических URL на новые статические

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Доброе времени суток!
Сделал преобразование динамических адресов на статические.
Подскажите пожалуйста, теперь как сделать Редирект со старых
динамических `URL`
на новые
статические.
Нужно сделать редирект с

`Site.ru/?q=рег`. Выражение

на

`site.ru/search/рег`. Выражение

Comment: только в ссылке не пользуйтесь кирилицей

Comment: Вот так вообще не работает редирект... (
3 дня мучаюсь уже, не могу найти решение.

Comment: я проверил на сайте http://htaccess.mwl.be/ и тесты все нормально проходять. там у вас точно кирилицы нету?

Comment: после добавления
RewriteRule ^search/
(.*)?(.*)$ search/$1?
[L,NC]

получаю ошибку 500

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так, исправил, теперь работает тоже

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/%1? [L]
```

UPD:

вот рабочий код

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)

RewriteRule ^$ search/%1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)?(.*)$ search/$1?  [L,NC]
```

тут самое главное, это знак `?` в конце. Он удаляет предыдушый запрос с `?q=...`

Comment: Не получается.
Я преобразовал site.ru/?q= на site.ru/search/
и теперь когда делаю редирект так:
RewriteCon
d %{QUERY_
STRING}
^q=
([0-9]*)$
RewriteRul
e ^(.*)$
search/
%1 [L]

на странице search/blabla
получаю содержание
?q=blabla
тоесть получаю опять редирекр который выше сделали. И ошибку 301.

Comment: @Идентикон проверьте update

Comment: @Идентикон попробуйте первый вариант, там я его изменил. тоже должен работать. если 2й не сработал у вас

Comment: Попробывал оба варианта, нивкакую. Тестер ругается на флаги Л я их заменил на Р , редирект получается но открывается страница ошибки 302(301).
Если не делать редирект, навредит сайту это?
Ведь получается дубликат страниц.
onmuz.ru/?q=olga
и
onmuz.ru/search/olga
одно и тоже содержание.